# Can I infer method generic type by generic specified in interface in Java?

Tags: java, generics, interface

Basically I need implement an interface like this:

```
// T denotes input type, R for output type
public interface Seg<T, R> {
  int put(T);
  R get(int key);
}
```

Now I find out that there is a functional dependency between T and R, like:

```
T: int --(infer)--> R: String
T: float --(infer)--> R:ByteBuffer
```

So now I am wondering is it possible that I only specify T with the interface, and infer the R with T?

---

For an example, code below is what I need (of course it cannot be complied):

```java
public interface Seg<T> {
  int put(T);
  // infer the return type rather than specify in interface
  (T==Integer ? String : ByteBufjfer) get(int key);
}
```

---

Any single word will be much appreciated, and I would be very grateful if you put forward any clue for a systematical learning of these things.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "infer `R` *with* `T`". What code do you want to write, that you currently cannot? Can you show some code that doesn't compile?

Comment: @Sweeper Thank you for your advice !  I edited the question, you can inform me if not enough yet.

Comment: I do not see a relationship between int and String, nor between float and ByteBuffer.  By “infer”, do you mean something like your application uses those pairs of types (eg somewhere you have a `Map<Integer, String>` and `Map<Float, ByteBuffer>`) ?

Comment: Sounds like you just need two different interfaces, one of them being non-generic, with `int put(int)` and `String get(int)`.

Comment: You certainly cannot do `T==Integer`, since type erasure means that whatever type T is is not available at runtime.

Comment: @Sweeper In fact, I only need these 2 interface right now, which are Seg<Int, Str> and Seg<Float, ByteBuffer>. I want to implements them by one interface with generic types since they have totally same methods.

Comment: This is a misuse of generics. You should use generics when your type works for an *infinite* number of `T`s, not just two. Just write two interfaces.

Comment: @racraman Thank you, and thats nearly true! I only need these 2 interface right now: Seg<Int, Str> and Seg<Float, ByteBuffer>. But I am not sure whether could be more further days.

Comment: @Sweeper Yes that is a solution indeed, but now I am not sure whether there will be more interface implementing other combination of types, like Seg<int, int>, Seg <int, float>... I means how should I implement these instance of Seg which can put and get different types, and the type of output can be infered by the type of input.

Comment: Right, you only need `Seg<Integer, String>` now but might need others later.   The thing is, those others later may very include `Map<Integer, ByteBuffer>`.   As @Sweeper says, generics means for ALL `T`s, not just a few (although you can limit using `<T super Something>`, etc - but that’s still ALL `T`s within that)